# Refresh Page C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, refresh

Is there a Page.Refresh type of command to refresh a page?

I don't want to redirect to the page or refresh in JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want a full page cycle? If so, the solutions provided should work. However, you said you don't want to redirect... so I'm not exactly sure what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Fermin nailed it.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I think this should do the trick (untested):

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: I know this post was a long time ago. But I have just bumped into it and I was wondering why your second parameter in "true". As far as I know, the best practice is actually "false" when using the Response.Redirect. What do you think?

Comment: In general "false" is better practice as "true" causes a ThreadAbortException to be thrown, which is costly. As always though it depends on your requirements.

Comment: I almost feel bad upvoting this because it is such an easy answer!

Answer (score 20):

Careful with rewriting URLs, though. I'm using this, so it keeps URLs rewritten.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
```

Comment: Watch out that can be used to do XSS exploits.  You're blindly trusting the URL from the user.  You'd be better off to do Response.Redirect( "~AbsolutePage.aspx" );

Comment: Can someone enlighten me on how this would be used to do XSS? It redirects to current page, and cannot do more than this page allows, no?

Comment: This is the current page URL, not a return URL query string parameter.. I don't see the XSS in this either.

Answer (score 6):

You can just do a regular postback to refresh the page if you don't want to redirect.  Posting back from any control will run the page lifecycle and refresh the page.

To do it from javascript, you can just call the __doPostBack() function.

Comment: Wow, harsh. Pretty liberal with the downvotes there hey? He also said no redirects, and it was completely an aside to the rest of the answer.

Comment: I didnt find the answer useful, so I clicked the down arrow.  That's just what I do.  No offense!

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use:

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

because this might cause a runtime error.

A better approach is:

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), false);
        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what exactly you require, a `Server.Transfer` might be a resource-cheaper alternative to `Response.Redirect`. More information is in *[Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm)*.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Path);
```

If you have to check for the Request.Params when the page is refresh use below. This will not rewrite the Request.Params to the URL.

```
Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Path + "?Remove=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use # for Current page url address at Redirect to Refresh and that working currectly.
What do you think about this:

```
Response.Redirect("#")
```

Answer (score -3):

Call Page_load function:

`Page_Load(sender, e);`

Answer (score -5):

To refresh the whole page, but it works normally:

```
Response.Redirect(url,bool)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Could you explain what you mean by it working 'normal'?  Details are great for people who come by and see your answer later!